# Existence of a method to analyse and filter abusive images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently developing an app in Rails that is based on images upload and I was wondering if there is a technique to analyse images in a back-end enviroment and tell if each of these images contains or not abusive content such as sexual content.

It's been a while that I have this doubt because I can't imagine that all the "big sites" have only humans to filter thousands of images.

Comment: Google has a filter, perhaps there is some way that you can use it. They also have a mechanism to report objectionable images so they probably have been improving it over the years.

Comment: Sites with user content usually have a "report" or "flag" button, and depending on their size, admin staff who will respond to these and may or may not review new content as it comes in. That mechanism is IMO one of the most effective. Handling large amounts of user content, and keeping content to a "PG" or "U" standard is unfortunately a cost sink for many sites, same as keeping buildings free of graffiti or areas of natural beauty free of rubbish is a cost sink for governments and councils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**People** are better than **computers** at understanding semantic content.

"Abusive" is in the eye of the beholder and it is doubtful that this will ever be a machine-computable problem.

In general if your problem involves the recognition of patterns, use people,
just google "mechanical turk".

There are exceptions but they are few, there is blood on the highway of AI.